# Starting a Career in Theoretical Computer Science

Tags: advice-request

I am a third year mathematics student from Nigeria. I'm considering diving into theoretical Computer science after my B.sc in Mathematics, but the only computer science course that I've done is just an Introduction to computing in my first year.

Though I've read some topics concerning my question like this: [one](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/19498/career-in-theoretical-computer-science), but I still want to know if I'm still qualified for a career in Theoretical Computer Science.

Comment: Generally speaking, I'd say yes? Try to take an Algorithms class, an Intro to Theory of Computing class, or a Intro Computational Complexity class and see what you think. If you're interested in CS Theory PhD programs, I can say they take people w math degrees all the time, but certainly the more you can demonstrate your interest and relevant background (by CS Theory classes, an undergrad research experience, etc) the better. Lots more can be said abt advice for cs-theory PhD programs, but without more details of your situatuon I'd leave it at that. Feel free to email me.

Comment: Okay @JoshuaGrochow, thanks. How can I get your email because I could'nt find it on your user profile sir.

Comment: https://home.cs.colorado.edu/~jgrochow/