# What are some interesting applications of homotopical algebra in theoretical computer science?

Tags: big-list, algebraic-topology

I am an homotopy theorist, interested in computer science.

I would like to ask what are some interesting applications of homotopical algebra (model categories, infinity categories, simplicial categories, etc) in theoretical computer science?

Comment: Related: [here](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/2898/12739) and [here](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/31325/12739).

Answer (score 3):

Two big applications of homotopy theory in theoretical computer science are

1. [Homotopy Type Theory](https://homotopytypetheory.org/) revealed a completely unexpected connection between the theory of the typed lambda calculus and homotopy theory. As a quick intuition, think of it as either a (vast) generalization of the connection between intuitionistic logic and topological spaces, or a language for doing "synthetic homotopy theory".
2. The [directed version of algebraic topology and homotopy theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/directed+homotopy+theory) (ie, where paths are not reversible) has been developed precisely with applications to computer science in mind. The intuition is that the possible evaluations of a concurrent program correspond to a space, program executions correspond to paths in that space, and synchronization primitives correspond to obstructions. By considering the geometric properties of these spaces/programs, it becomes possible to develop tools for reasoning about their behaviour.

Answer (score 2):

*My answer to a related [post: Applications for set theory, ordinal theory, infinite combinatorics and general topology in computer science?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/31577/12739):*

[The 2004 Gödel Prize](http://www.math.utu.fi/icalp04/godel2004.html) was shared by the following two papers:

- *The Topological Structure of Asynchronous Computation*.
  By Maurice Herlihy and Nir Shavit, Journal of the ACM, Vol. 46 (1999), 858-923
- *Wait-Free k-Set Agreement Is Impossible: The Topology of Public Knowledge*.
  By Michael Saks and Fotios Zaharoglou, SIAM J. on Computing, Vol. 29 (2000), 1449-1483.

Quotes from [the 2004 Gödel Prize:](http://www.math.utu.fi/icalp04/godel2004.html)

> The two papers offer one of the most important breakthroughs in the theory of distributed computing.
>
> The discovery of the **topological nature of distributed computing** provides a new perspective on the area and represents one of the most striking examples, possibly in all of applied mathematics, of the use of topological structures to quantify natural computational phenomena.

---

*Added:*

A book on this topic:

[Distributed Computing Through Combinatorial Topology, 1st Edition, 2013](http://store.elsevier.com/Distributed-Computing-Through-Combinatorial-Topology/Maurice-Herlihy/isbn-9780124045781/)

Comment: While I am a big fan of these results, it's not clear to me if they count as *homotopical* algebra so much as just *homological* algebra...

Comment: @JoshuaGrochow Honestly, I know little about these results. I am interested in distributed computing and know of these results. However, I have little mathematical background to understand them well. Please feel free to modify/delete my answer. Thanks.